# Windows Server 2008 R2 max open files limit

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, limitations, files

Does Windows Server 2008 R2 have similar limitations to [maximum number of opened files](http://www.linuxhowtos.org/Tips%20and%20Tricks/ulimit.htm) like linux have?

Answer (score 8):

Windows Servers have limitations on maximum connected users and maximum open files per session.
These are default settings:

- Maximum Logged On Users: 16777216
- Maximum open files per session: 16384

You can view them with `net config server` command.

Comment: Those limits apply to network access to files: not local (including within a remote desktop session).

Comment: Richard, thanks for the comment, didn't know about local access.

Answer (score 6):

Windows **have** limits on the number of Open File Handles.It will be around  16,711,680 on 64 bit machines and on 32 bit machines it will be 16,744,448.

*64 BIT*

[image]

[image]

*32 BIT*

[image]

[image]

This is the reference Microsoft Blog Post ***Pushing the Limits of Windows by Mark Russinovich*** https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/markrussinovich/2009/09/29/pushing-the-limits-of-windows-handles/